# How to get the import working?

Tags: google-maps-for-ee, google-maps, objective-html

I'm sure this addon was supposed to be making my life easier...

Trying to get the import utility of Google Maps for EE working. I'm only have 9 entries I'm trying to upload at first until I know things are okay, but can't even get anywhere with that. When I run it, nothing happens other than the Total Import Time ticking away. Thirty minutes has passed so far and nothing.

Anyone got any advice for things I can start looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Emptied the exp_gmap_import_stats table and tried again and it worked.